# Premiere Pro: Scale effect ends after keyframe

Tags: video, adobe-premiere

I've googled around and couldn't find anything. I'm trying to zoom & pan into a spot on my video and the zoom effect is ending where you see the marker in the video, clearly after the last keyframe where it should be ending. What could be causing this, and how can I get the zoom to end where it's supposed to, instead of being "offset" by several seconds.

[image: Premiere Pro Effects Control]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `Time remapping` you can see in the picture is set to `89.4%`. I had pressed `Remove all Effects` multiple times, but this does not remove Time Remapping effects for whatever reason. Upon resetting it to `100%` my problem is gone.